# text decoration set to be none while tabing with ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I would like to set the `text-decoration: none` while tabbing on Internet Explorer 7. At the same time I have to show `text-decoration` while hovering over the element. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want to remove the dotted outline of focused elements, like when a link is marked by tabbing to it?

Comment: No Anders, You are talking about setting the outline property. My problem is that I have set the text-decoration: underline on hovering. But the text-decoration also working with tabing too on ie7, that I need to remove. Hope it's clear

Comment: Please show us your code. You must at least have code that removes the default underlining from links. Exactly how do you do that?

Comment: Jukka - Tried to show you the code on Jsfiddle, but assumes the tab functionality is not properly working with ie7 on Jsfiddle.  Anyway Please refer this link, you can find exactly the same issue here http://www.redmine.org/

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually reproduce your error. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NnKxx/1/

In IE7 it all works nice - if I tab to the elements they aren't underlined, only when I hover over them. This is without using the CSS I mentioned above.

Thing is in IE7 the `:focus` selector doesn't work, so it should be enough to just do the following:

```
a {text-decoration:none;} /* this is important! */
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: Anders, tnx for you time. You can find the issue here http://www.redmine.org/ . Please have a look

Comment: I've had a look in IE7 and it doesn't show underlines for any link when marking them with tab - only when hovering over them. A tad confusing...

Comment: Strange :( . Will update you if got any solution.. once again thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a default behavior in IE browser. Apply the fix's like border:none, text-decoration:none and outline:none; does not work.